# string replacement issues with bbcode in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, unity-game-engine

I have a series of words coupled with their definitions and I want to add some bbcode around every instance of the word inside the definition.

To achieve this I have the following code:

```
wd[1] = Regex.Replace(wd[1],@"\b"+wd[0]+@"\b","[ffa500]"+wd[0]+"[-]");
```

where wd[0] is the word and wd[1] is the definition.

This works for single words but does not when wd[0] contains commas or exclamation points. For instance, it works when wd[0] contains "break dance" or "" but does not for "ay, caramba!".

Any idea why this is happening?

**Edit:**

I should add that for "ay, carumba!" and some other words I have the italic bbcode [i][/i] around the word in the definition, but that is not the case for all words found in the definition. I would like the solution to work regardless, any way to achieve this?

Comment: I believe the word boundary occurs between "caramba" and "!"  and "!" is not a word so it is not followed by a word boundary assuming that there is a space before the next word.

Comment: the word itself: wd[0], contains the !. In that specific instance, wd[0] = "ay, carumba!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that punctuation is not considered to be part of a word, specifically it is not included in the `\w` class.  That means that if your "word" ends with punctuation then that will not be followed by a word boundary `\b` unless there is a word immediately following the punctuation.  So for your example, "\bay, caramba!\b", it would not match "ay, caramba! What is going on?" or "ay, caramba!", but would match "ay, caramba!No Space.".  You might be able to try matching word boundaries, non word characters, or the beginning or end of the line instead like this.

```
wd[1] = Regex.Replace(
    wd[1],
    @"(^|\b|\W)"+wd[0]+@"(\b|\W|$)",
    "$1[ffa500]"+wd[0]+"[-]$2");
```

Notice that you have to add the `$1` and `$2` groups in the replacement string in case they matched non-word characters (`\W`).

**EDIT**

And here's how you can do a case insensitive match without changing the case in the replacement.

```
wd[1] = Regex.Replace(
    wd[1],
    @"(^|\b|\W)(" + wd[0] + @")(\b|\W|$)",
    "$1[ffa500]$2[-]$3",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Further you might want to consider escaping `wd[0]` when you use it in the pattern in case it contains special regular expression characters like `.` and `*`.

```
wd[1] = Regex.Replace(
    wd[1],
    @"(^|\b|\W)(" + Regex.Escape(wd[0]) + @")(\b|\W|$)",
    "$1[ffa500]$2[-]$3",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: That did not work either :( I should add that I also have an [i][/i] bbcode around "ay, carumba!". But that is not the case for all words, therefore I would like the solution to work regardless of having a space, or anything else before/after the word.

Comment: @kUr4m4 Can you show specifically what the values of `wd[0]` and `wd[1]` are when this does not work.

Comment: @kUr4m4 if the word is "as" I assume you don't want it to match "has" or "assume", right?

Comment: the exact value for wd[0] and wd[1] for when they don't work are:

wd[0] = "ay, carumba!"
wd[1] = "[i]Ay, carumba![/i] is a Spanish phrase that people sometimes say, especially when they are surprised or when they don’t like something. Even people who don’t speak Spanish sometimes say [i]ay, carumba![/i]".

After posting this I realized that it actually works now, the issue is that the first "Ay, carumba!" has the first "a" in upper case, therefore it wouldn't detect it...

Comment: @kUr4m4 You could use the overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes a `RegexOptions` and pass `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: yes I know but that would remove the upper case from the definition right?

Comment: @kUr4m4 Yes, unless you put the match in a group and used that in the replacement.  So a pattern of `@"(^|\b|\W)("+wd[0]+@")(\b|\W|$)"` and a replacement string of `"$1[ffa500]$2[-]$3"`

Comment: @kUr4m4 See my edit regarding the case issue and potential issues with special regular expression characters.

Comment: That's really great! Already accepted it has an answer! Thank you very much for all the help and for going the extra mile to explain everything!